# HtmlParser for Android using Jsoup

Tags: java, android, jsoup

I'm trying to parse a HttpResponse content in my Android code
I'm aware of the Jsoup library to parse the html response in DOM way.
The body of the http response is almost similar to this snippet.

```
<body> 
<div id="Layout"><script type="text/javascript" language="JavaScript">ev(24,20,1,3,'15-04-2015 12:04:08 PM',2,16,'15-04-2015 12:04:22 PM',3,10,'15-04-2015 12:21:02 PM, ... , 20,17,'15-04-2015 05:54:17 PM');</script>
</div>     
</body>
```

Now in order for me to read the content as below

```
24,20,1,3,'15-04-2015 12:04:08 PM',2,16,'15-04-2015 12:04:22 PM',3,10,'15-04-2015 12:21:02 PM, ... , 20,17,'15-04-2015 05:54:17 PM'
```

From

```
ev(24,20,1,3,'15-04-2015 12:04:08 PM',2,16,'15-04-2015 12:04:22 PM',3,10,'15-04-2015 12:21:02 PM, ... , 20,17,'15-04-2015 05:54:17 PM');
```

I have an option to parse the body of the response

```
Document doc = Jsoup.parseBodyFragment(htmlresponse); //htmlresponse is a string
Element body = doc.body();
```

However I need to read the contents between **ev(** *CONTENT* **);**
Can I use Pattern matching in such cases or kindly suggest a better approach.

Thanks

Comment: U could split on every '

Comment: What should I do inorder to read the data after the second comma ','  i.e.,  If the input is : ev(24,20,1,3,'15-04-2015 12:04:08 PM'...., I have to read 1,3,'15-04-2015 12:04:08 PM' in a loop. I'm clueless at this place

Answer (score 0):

I can't test it right now, but I think you can try this:

```
Elements layout = doc.select("#Layout");
String script = layout.select("script").text();
String ev = script.substring(3, script.length()-1);
```